# How to detect all nodes or specific nodes in a touchBegins

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In iOS 7's SpriteKit framework, I am attempting to build a simple game for the purposes of learning the framework.  One area I am tripping over a little bit is how to detect a specific node when there are multiple nodes overlapping under a touch.  Let me give an example:

In a basic chess training game, I can drag a piece forward one tile, but what happens after that is dependent on what other nodes are in that space.  I want to know which tile the touch is on, regardless of any other nodes which happen to also be on that tile node.  The problem I am running into is that the touch seems to detect the uppermost node.  So my question would be:

What is the recommended solution for detecting the tile node?  I was thinking about using zPosition in some way but I have yet to determine how to do that. Any suggestions?

Another approach would be to detect ALL nodes under a touch. Is there a way to grab all nodes and put them in an array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Iterate through the nodes at the touched point:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];
    for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
       //go through nodes, get the zPosition if you want
       int nodePos = node.zPosition;

       //or check the node against your nodes
       if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"myNode1"]) {
           //...
       }

       if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"myNode2"]) {
           //...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sorta works, but if I have a Parent sprite, and a child sprite and I want to check if my click is on the parent it isnt working. If I click on the child sprite it always returns true for clicking the parent even if that click is not on the parent, i.e. a person sprite is parent, the arm is child. Click arm which is away from parent the click will return true for parent.

Comment: A little old now, but in case someone else stumbles on this post. You need to set userInteractionEnabeled = NO, on child nodes that don't have their own touch detection implemented. Otherwise the touches will be intercepted, but there will be no way to handle them.

Comment: @BeauYoung when i do this nothing is changed, i read that all sprite's default `userInteractionEnabled` is NO, how else can i prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the tile at a given point, since you would know the frame of the board and therefore the size of each tile.

E.g. Assume you have a board whose frame is {10, 50, 160, 160}. You know therefore that the size of each tile would be 20x20. If you have a touch at point {x,y} You know that the index of the row touched is `(x-10)/20` and the index of the column is `(y-50)/20`. Oh, and you would probably need to use `floorf` in that calculation too.

Alternatively, and to actually answer your question, you could use the `nodesAtPoint:` method to get all the nodes at a given point :)